# Replace string and count occurrence of Alphabets in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

hi i have a string of this type "061801850010300-09/A/B", what i wanna do is that i want to replace "/" with "-".

Replace "A" with "1" and "B" with "2"

I mean i wanna show the mathematical occurrence of A as 1 , B as 2, C as 3...  Z as 26 so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = "061801850010300-09/A/B"
.replace(/\//g, '-')
.replace(/[A-Z]/ig, function(c){
   return c.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0)-64; 
});
```

Comment: it returned me correct value for 1st occurrence of "/A" as "-1" but later occurrences were missed.

Comment: worked now thx gonna test few times more. then i will mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can match everything that you want to replace, and make an expression to replace it with the right thing:

```
input = input.replace(/([\/A-Z])/g, function(m) {
  return m == "/" ? "-" : m.charCodeAt(0) - 64
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/g2sgb/

Comment: This doesn’t look like JavaScript.

Comment: @MathiasBynens: I misses that. I rewrote it for Javascript.

Comment: @Guffa `'A'.charCodeAt(0) == 65`, not `1`.